# How do I code the jradiobutton being cliked and adding a score

Tags: java

I am doing a quiz after a short course app. 
I want to have a separate JFrame for the quiz, when I click  submit it will show you how many correct answers.

```
int score;
   if jRadioButton3.Is();
  score = score + 1;
```

Comment: You should probably remove the `;` after the `if`.

Comment: That's not how you would declare an if-statement, also `score = score + 1` can be written like this: `score += 1` which technically adds 1 to the current score. This is what it should look like `if (jRadioButton3.Is()) { score += 1 }`

Comment: I *java* the right tag? You code does not look like Java...